# do a check if id does not exist do something

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I am trying to find if user has sent a friend request or not. if user has not sent any request I would like to show send request button.

So I have a table called friends

```
id
user_id
friend_id
reqs_status which can be 0,1,2

reqs_status = 0 meaning request already sent and waiting for approval
reqs_status = 1 meaning show Accept or Reject button
reqs_status = 2 meaning they are friends already
No row existing meaning not sent any request [show send request button]

If user A sends request to B. I create 2 rows one saying
user_id 1 sent a request to friend_id 2 with reqs_status as 0 and 
another as inverse user_id 2 got request from friend_id 1 with reqs_status as 1
```

**Here reqs_status play key role in showing right buttons on screen. like: already taken user, friend request sent, send request, accept/reject button,etc..**

Now my data looks something like:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":9,
      "firstname":"Hattie",
      "lastname":"Cropper",
      "email":"hgc3@org.uk",
      "role":1,
      "friends":[  
         {  
            "id":7,
            "user_id":8,
            "friend_id":9,
            "reqs_status":2,

         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":21,
      "firstname":"Jon",
      "lastname":"Olson",
      "email":"jo185@org.uk",
      "role":1,
      "friends":[  
         {  
            "id":19,
            "user_id":20,
            "friend_id":21,
            "reqs_status":2,

         },
         {  
            "id":29,
            "user_id":23,
            "friend_id":21,
            "reqs_status":1,

         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":24,
      "firstname":"Jessica",
      "lastname":"Jensen",
      "email":"jj61@org.uk",
      "role":1,
      "friends":[  
         {  
            "id":24,
            "user_id":25,
            "friend_id":24,
            "reqs_status":2,

         },
         {  
            "id":30,
            "user_id":23,
            "friend_id":24,
            "reqs_status":0,
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

if no request sent meaning there is no data in friends table.

```
@foreach ($user['friends'] as $friend)
@if($friend['reqs_status'] == 0 && $friend['user_id'] == $myid)
//show button already sent
@elseif($friend['reqs_status'] == 1 && $friend['user_id'] == $myid)
//show accept reject button
@elseif ($friend['user_id']== '')
//show send request button
@endif
@endforeach
```

I cant do @else because there are array of friends and for each of those other friends there would be a button.Instead I want to use elseif **check if user_id does not exist in a friends array list then show send request button. if I do $friend['user_id']!= $myid that means if a user has 10 friends and in none my id exists it would add 10 buttons rather than adding single button** I need a single action for whole bunch of no.

Above condition :  `@elseif ($friend['user_id']== '')` fails. I dont know how to compare something that does not exists in the first place :/

I hope you understand the issue. If its not clear let me know in comments, I will try to clear with you as possible in chat or so.

One possible thing that would suffice for this issue would be if a match is found ($myid) in any of the array object it should ignore other objects in an array, some sort of break or skip or continue but if no match found in entire array do X thing which would be to create a single button.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use this code it will solve your problem!

```html
 @foreach ($user['friends'] as $friend)
@if($friend['user_id'] == $myid)
@switch ($friend['reqs_status'])
case 0:
//show button already request sent
break;
case 1:
//show accept and reject request button
break;
case 2:
//meaning they are friends already
default:
# code...
break;
@endswitch
@elseif(empty($friends['user_id']))
//show send request button
@endif
@endforeach
```

Please Let me know if you have any queries!

Comment: I used your code as suggested but the switch case code seems to print on screen and blade engine does not seem to catch that